# How does a router know who to send a new message to when every single host listen to the same port?

Tags: java, networking

I am a junior software developer with basic background in networking but i've had a specific question in my head for a long time. I am currently designing a P2P chat app based on Java. It works on localhost, haven't tried on different machines/same local network and different machine on different networks but i wonder: if let's say 5 machines are waiting for a request with a `socket.accept()` on the same port, fully knowing each client is also the server (P2P), when a computer from another networks sends a request on the IP each of these 5 computres share, how does a router know who to send a connection request to when it is a new request and every clients utilize the same IP/port ?

Will they all receive the same packet or will the router chose only one machine to receive this packet ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Routers typically only deal with **IP addresses**, which your question mentions nothing about. I think that indicates where you should spend time researching.

Comment: "the IP each of these 5 computres share" - 5 distinct computers won't share the same IP

Comment: Publicly they will, each will then be sorted by their port number with PAT over NAT. but how one on the outside could then point to one on the Inside ?

Comment: @Anon Assuming NAT/PAT is in use... Even if it is, there will still always be five distinct IP/port _pairs_. So the packet will be sent to whichever computer has the _matching_ IP _and_ port.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but as far as I remember it is more or less random and only 1 will receive the Package.
Anyways try and have a look [here.](https://www.quora.com/Can-a-socket-of-a-server-be-used-by-multiple-clients-simultaneously)